# MySQL - Count all rows for each day of week but for each sender

Tags: mysql, sql, count, union-all

I have this query which outputs the count of rows for each day and if there are no rows, it outputs 0.

I now have an additional field I want to add into the query called 'Sender'. I need the query to do exactly the same but for each of the senders.

How can I perform a query so each Sender gets each day of the week with the values?

```
SELECT DAYNAME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL Days.n DAY)) AS `day`,
       COUNT(r.List_Date) AS `total`
FROM (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 as n UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 as n UNION ALL SELECT 4 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as n UNION ALL SELECT 6 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 as n
     ) Days LEFT JOIN
     returns r
     ON r.List_Date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL Days.n DAY)
GROUP BY Days.n
ORDER BY Days.n DESC
```

Comment: `group by sender, days.n`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `cross join` to get all the rows (each sender and each day of the week).  Then use the `left join`:

```
SELECT s.sender, DAYNAME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL Days.n DAY)) AS `day`,
       COUNT(r.List_Date) AS `total`
FROM (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 as n UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 as n UNION ALL SELECT 4 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as n UNION ALL SELECT 6 as n UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 as n
     ) Days CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM returns) s LEFT JOIN
     returns r
     ON r.List_Date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL Days.n DAY) and
        r.sender = s.sender
GROUP BY s.sender, Days.n
ORDER BY s.sender, Days.n DESC;
```

This uses the `returns` table to get the appropriate senders.  If you have another table, you can use that instead.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff,. Does exactly what I want